# how do we deal with not knowing the prefix/namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xsd

**How do I iterate through a specific xpath against an `XmlDocument` that has no prefix/namespace** ?

I'm parsing XML like so :

```
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(input);
        var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace(nsPrefix, ns);
        var nodes = doc.SelectNodes(xpath, nsmgr);
```

This works totally fine when the `nsPrefix` as well as the `ns` are passed in and *non-empty*.

However, when the namespace/prefix are empty for example in this scenario:

[image]

Then I am unable to correctly parse the XML.

The full function is:

```
public static class XPathWalker
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetListOfAttachments(string input, string xpath, string nsPrefix, string ns)
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(input);
            var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace(nsPrefix, ns);
            var nodes = doc.SelectNodes(xpath, nsmgr);
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.InnerText))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                yield return node.InnerText;
            }
        }
    }
```

**How do I iterate through a specific xpath against an `XmlDocument` that has no prefix/namespace** ?

Comment: If you don't care about namespaces at all and you want to instead use `System.Xml.Linq` you can [use LocalName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xname.localname?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks! but that would mean i would have re-implement. is there a bandaid solution ?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb "possible" dont pay the bills, are you saying that with xmldocument its _impossible_ to ignore the namespace?

Comment: I don't really know, it's been a long time since I used `XmlDocument`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was indeed a way to do this with `XmlDocument`. Firstly, I had to convert the input `string` to a `stream`:

```
// convert string to stream
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

Once I had my `stream`, I was able to feed it into `XmlDocument`. Here's the full code:

```
        string input = @"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>etc..";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        var nodes = doc.SelectNodes(xpath);
        using (var tr = new XmlTextReader(stream))
        {
            tr.Namespaces = false;
            doc.Load(tr);
        }
```